# Heroku doesn't open index.html

Tags: html, node.js, heroku

I have deployed an application successfully but when trying to run the app on Heroku, I am getting below error:

```
2022-01-02T05:26:45.612777+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-01-02T05:26:46.989656+00:00 app[web.1]: > tic-tac-toe@1.0.0 start /app
2022-01-02T05:26:46.989657+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run open
2022-01-02T05:26:47.536042+00:00 app[web.1]: > tic-tac-toe@1.0.0 open /app
2022-01-02T05:26:47.536043+00:00 app[web.1]: > open index.html
2022-01-02T05:26:47.539616+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: open: not found
2022-01-02T05:26:47.543563+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2022-01-02T05:26:47.543721+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2022-01-02T05:26:47.543782+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2022-01-02T05:26:47.543850+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2022-01-02T05:26:47.546906+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! tic-tac-toe@1.0.0 open: `open index.html`
```

When I am running it on my system, the node scripts run just fine. Can someone please suggest what could be wrong?

The scripts in package.json are:
 `"scripts": { "start": "npm run open", "open": "open index.html" },`

Comment: Why should you open the index.html on the server side in Browser? They usally run headless without a Window system, so you cant use an Graphical applications there. I think you missunderstand that and want to serve the index.html to the client over http

Comment: The Heroku deploy system needs a start script to run the application and to open the index.html file I had to use nodeJS open command. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Write a node.js http server that servers the index.html. Its unclear what you want, this sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by creating a node server and adding a script to serve the index.html.

It is kind of unnecessary but that's how Heroku expects us to work. Cheers :)